# How can I get a list of dinos from an Excel Spreadsheet and insert them into specific positions in an HTML page?

Tags: html, excel, list

Hello there I could use some help!

My 14 year old niece has a science project. She has a numbered list of animals - dinosaurs - in an Excel spreadsheet. She asked me to help her, and I could not say no, but I am only a very lame beginner html programmer.

So I need to display the list of animals in the html page in two ways: In numerical order AND in classification order (carnivorous / herbivorous etc)  together with a small picture of each animal.

The objective is to show them as in the annexed picture, one page in alphabetical order, and the other page in classification order (feeding habits, land or maritime, etc.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsyjl.jpg)

I know how to create a html block, but then I would have to insert the dinos one by one, and my / her deadline is next week. The list has over two hundred dinos, so I can´t do it by hand. Then it ocurred to me there must be a way to get the data from the Excel and display it in html in the desired order (alphabetical or by characteristic), but I don´t know how to do this. I know this is basic stuff for you, but can anybody PLEASE help me? Thank you in advance!

Oh yes, the html blocks I am making are like this:

**32 - Triceratops**
Triassico
Triceratops

Comment: what is the excel structure? is it `NAME | TYPE | WEIGHT | IMG`, if yes maybe is possible

Comment: Yes, it is that way, only the IMG column is not yet there, but I could create it. But should I put a hyperlink to the jpg file in my computer? Or should I embed the file? Or copy-paste the jpg inside the spreadsheet cell?

Comment: no copy paste the image is bad idea. I suggest the link of the dinos images `./img/myDino.png` or `https://example.com/img/myDino.png` format

Comment: @humblebegginer I added a answer now, if it solve the problem please upvote and accept (i tried to put everything and also how to do)

Comment: Dear Laaouatni Anas, thank you so much for your answer and orientation, you are so so kind. I will try to set it up and will tell you the result tomorrow. But I think it is going to work. May God bless you!

Comment: @humblebegginer ok, see you then :)

Answer (score 0):

### final result

[image]

### instructions

1. open your excel file, and save it.
2. find the file of the excel in your desktop/folders.
3. go to the https://tableconvert.com/excel-to-json
4. drag the excel file to the website input to get the JSON

> JSON is the simple key-value format, that we can use in javascript.
>
>  so we use this website to translate the excel to an easier format :)

5. here is the example excel I created *(these are fake values because I am not an expert on dinos, but you can use your own values)*

[image]

6. after pasting the excel/or dragging it, you will get the results in JSON format.

    like you see below

[image]

7. copy the JSON code of the results.
8. paste the JSON inside a javascript file and assign it to a variable.

```js
// this is an example
const dinoData = [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}];
```

9. in the HTML we will create a wrapper container

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

10. inside the card, we will add the card divs

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="card">...</div>
  <div class="card">...</div>
  <div class="card">...</div>
</div>
```

> but with javascript.

10. so we can reuse the HTML by wrapping the code inside the `<template>`

```html
<template>
  <div class="card">...</div>
</template>
```

11. inside the cards, we will add some HTML tags that we add them with the info in JS

```html
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="image" />
    <span class="name"></span>
    <span class="type"></span>
    <span class="weight"></span>
  </div>
</template>
```

12. now we can get do a loop on the array by using `forEach`

```js
dinoData.forEach((dino) => {
  // do this test first, to check if all the things are correct
  console.log(dino);
});
```

13. copy the card in javascript using `.cloneNode(true)`

```js
const card = document.querySelector("#card-template").content;

dinoData.forEach((dino) => {
  let newCard = card.cloneNode(true);
}
```

14. change the text inside the card by using `.textContent`

```js
newCard.querySelector(".name").textContent = dino.name;
newCard.querySelector(".type").textContent = dino.type;
newCard.querySelector(".weight").textContent = dino.weight;
newCard.querySelector(".image").src = dino.image;
```

15. at the end add the card to the HTML by using `.appendChild()`

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container") ?? document.body;

container.appendChild(newCard);
```

16. we can implement now sorting code.

[image]

17. alphabetically

```js
function sortAlfabetic(cards) {
  const sorted = [...cards].sort((a, b) => {
    return `${a.querySelector(".name").textContent}`.localeCompare(
      `${b.querySelector(".name").textContent}`,
    );
  });

  sorted.forEach((sortedCard, index) => { 
    sortedCard.classList.add(`order-${index}`);
  });
}
```

As you see we used [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to order them alphabetically

also, another thing, don't use `cards` parameter directly but use `[...cards]` instead because this makes a copy and does not change the original one.

also for sorting strings, we used [`.localCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) which returns us an index of the string character order.

> example:
>
> - "a", "a" = 0
> - "a", "b" = -1
> - "a", "c" = -2
> - "c", "a" = 2
> - "d", "b" = 2

[image]

18. show only carnivorous

```js
function showOnlyCarnivorous(cards) {
  const sorted = sortAlfabetic(cards).filter((card) => {
    return card.querySelector(".type").textContent == "carnivorous";
  });

  cards.forEach((card, index) => {
    card.classList.add(`hidden`);
  });

  sorted.forEach((sortedCard, index) => {
    sortedCard.classList.remove(`hidden`);
  });
}
```

19. show only Herbivorous

```js
function showOnlyHerbivorous(cards) {
  const sorted = sortAlfabetic(cards).filter((card) => {
    return card.querySelector(".type").textContent == "herbivorous";
  });

  cards.forEach((card, index) => {
    card.classList.add(`hidden`);
  });

  sorted.forEach((sortedCard, index) => {
    sortedCard.classList.remove(`hidden`);
  });
}
```

### complete code.

> I added some styling using a framework but you can delete it if you want and style it like you want.

```js
const dinoData = [{
    name: "my dino",
    type: "carnivorous",
    weight: "1000kg",
    image: "https://picsum.photos/559",
  },
  {
    name: "another dino",
    type: "herbivorous",
    weight: "350kg",
    image: "https://picsum.photos/560",
  },
  {
    name: "alex dino",
    type: "carnivorous",
    weight: "500kg",
    image: "https://picsum.photos/561",
  },
  {
    name: "hello dino",
    type: "carnivorous",
    weight: "10kg",
    image: "https://picsum.photos/562",
  },
  {
    name: "minecraft dino",
    type: "carnivorous",
    weight: "957kg",
    image: "https://picsum.photos/563",
  },
  {
    name: "js dino",
    type: "herbivorous",
    weight: "486kg",
    image: "https://picsum.photos/564",
  },
  {
    name: "fish dino",
    type: "carnivorous",
    weight: "400kg",
    image: "https://picsum.photos/565",
  },
];

const container = document.querySelector("#container") ?? document.body;
const card = document.querySelector("#card-template").content;

dinoData.forEach((dino) => {
  const newCard = card.cloneNode(true);

  newCard.querySelector(".name").textContent = dino.name;
  newCard.querySelector(".type").textContent = dino.type;
  newCard.querySelector(".weight").textContent = dino.weight;
  newCard.querySelector(".image").src = dino.image;

  container.appendChild(newCard);
});

let cardArray = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

/* alfabetic button */
document.querySelector("#btn-alf").addEventListener("click", () => {
  sortAlfabetic(cardArray);
});

/* carnivorous button */
document.querySelector("#btn-carn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  showOnlyCarnivorous(cardArray);
});

/* herbivorous button */
document.querySelector("#btn-herb").addEventListener("click", () => {
  showOnlyHerbivorous(cardArray);
});

function sortAlfabetic(cards) {
  const sorted = [...cards].sort((a, b) => {
    return `${a.querySelector(".name").textContent}`.localeCompare(
      `${b.querySelector(".name").textContent}`,
    );
  });

  sorted.forEach((sortedCard, index) => {
    sortedCard.classList.remove("hidden");
    sortedCard.classList.add(`order-${index}`);
  });

  return sorted;
}

function showOnlyCarnivorous(cards) {
  const sorted = sortAlfabetic(cards).filter((card) => {
    return card.querySelector(".type").textContent == "carnivorous";
  });

  cards.forEach((card, index) => {
    card.classList.add(`hidden`);
  });

  sorted.forEach((sortedCard, index) => {
    sortedCard.classList.remove(`hidden`);
  });
}

function showOnlyHerbivorous(cards) {
  const sorted = sortAlfabetic(cards).filter((card) => {
    return card.querySelector(".type").textContent == "herbivorous";
  });

  cards.forEach((card, index) => {
    card.classList.add(`hidden`);
  });

  sorted.forEach((sortedCard, index) => {
    sortedCard.classList.remove(`hidden`);
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-gray-50">
  <div class="w-full p-4 grid md:grid-cols-2 gap-4">
    <button id="btn-alf" class="bg-blue-500 p-4 w-full rounded-md text-lg font-bold text-white hover:bg-blue-700 transition">      sort by alfabeth</button>
    <div class="flex gap-4">
      <button id="btn-carn" class="bg-blue-500 p-4 w-full rounded-md text-lg font-bold text-white hover:bg-blue-700 transition"> carnivorous</button>
      <button id="btn-herb" class="bg-blue-500 p-4 w-full rounded-md text-lg font-bold text-white hover:bg-blue-700 transition"> herbivorous</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="container" class="grid sm:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-5 xl:grid-cols-6 2xl:grid-cols-7 gap-4 p-4"></div>

  <template id="card-template">
      <div
        class="card bg-white grid shadow-lg rounded-md p-4 transition hover:-translate-y-1"
      >
        <img class="image w-full h-auto rounded-md" />
        <span class="name">text1</span>
        <span class="type">text2</span>
        <span class="weight">text3</span>
      </div>
    </template>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```